# ExtJS5: Checkbox afterSubTpl wraps icons

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, template-engine, extjs5

The snippet below will not run on this site, but you can access a working demo [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/ey1ofw04/).

I am trying to get the icon to appear to the right of the checkbox, but it appears to be wrapping. Is there a property that I need to set so that it will appear in-line? This worked in ExtJS4, but after I switched to ExtJS5 this does not work.

[image]

## afterSubTpl Documentation

> ### [`Ext.form.field.Checkbox` -> `config` -> `afterSubTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-afterSubTpl)
>
> An optional string or XTemplate configuration to insert in the field markup after the subTpl markup. If an XTemplate is used, the component's render data serves as the context.

## Code

```js
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.define('App.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainView',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',
    title: 'Checkbox Template Example',
    referenceHolder: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
            tooltip = me.getHelpIconWithTooltip();
        me.items = [{
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'panel',
            title : 'A Panel Title',
            margin : 20,
            bodyStyle: 'padding: 8px;',
            layout : 'vbox',
            items : [{
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                fieldLabel : 'Checkbox',
                afterSubTpl: tooltip
            }]
        }],
        me.callParent();
    },
    
    getHelpIconWithTooltip: function () {
        return this.getFormIconWithTooltip('help-icon help-form-icon',
            'This is a help tooltip...');
    },

    getFormIconWithTooltip: function (iconClassList, toolTipText) {
        var getSpan = function(cl, qt) {
            return '<span class="'+cl+'" data-qtip="'+qt+'"></span>';
        }
        return [
            '<tpl>',
            getSpan(iconClassList, toolTipText),
            '</tpl>'
        ]; 
    }
});

Ext.define('App.app.App', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'App',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            flex: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'mainview'
            }]
        });
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.application('App.app.App');
});
```

```css
.help-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png) -705px -1125px no-repeat;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}

.help-form-icon {
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
```

---

## Edit

It looks like if I add a class to the checkbox, I can prevent it from wrapping, but now the icon is positioned too high.

[image]

```js
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Checkbox',
    afterSubTpl: tooltip,
    cls: 'no-wrap-tooltip'
}
```

```css
.no-wrap-tooltip .x-form-cb-wrap-inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out, but this solution uses magic numbers which make it work in this instance.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/ey1ofw04/)

```js
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Checkbox',
    afterSubTpl: tooltip,
    cls: 'no-wrap-tooltip'
}
```

```css
.no-wrap-tooltip .x-form-cb-wrap-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```